# `some incompatible instantiation of` when checking polymorphic functions

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, but when trying to work with polymorphic functions I keep hitting the same wall of `some incompatible instantiation of`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[Example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsDOAhEUC8UA8A8gEYBWANFAGqoIQB8AFCabvdbRJTSnQJRsozMoOIB7MSghIAdnwBQEAB5gxAJ2BQAxmJlpNERKkwgAXLCPosuIQDNKAN04Cc7RmJGuot92Rc48J14IPiA).

```
type EqualsBy = <Obj, Value>(Obj => Value, Value) => (Obj => boolean)
export const equalsBy: EqualsBy = (f, value) => (obj => f(obj) === value)
```

.

```
2: export const equalsBy: EqualsBy = (f, value) => (obj => f(obj) === value)
                                                              ^ Obj. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
2: export const equalsBy: EqualsBy = (f, value) => (obj => f(obj) === value)                                     
                                      ^ some incompatible instantiation of `Obj`
```

EDIT:
Easier [example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogjgVwIYBsDOAhEUC8UA8A8gEYBWANFAGqoIQB8AFCabvdbRJTSnZSwEo2UYgHtRKCEgB2AKAgAPMKIBOwKAGNR0tOoiJUmEAC5YB9FlxRGAM0oA3TpVFkhOdo97QcPqDcYupAJAA) with same problem:

```
type EqualsBy = <Obj, Value>(Obj => Value, Value, Obj) => boolean
export const equalsBy: EqualsBy = (f, value, obj) => value === f(obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll admit that I am often stumped by errors like this. Usually my strategies for addressing them are:

1. to stare really hard at the code and try to think of ways that
   it could mess up, and
2. to add gratuitous type annotations until the errors disappear or I get a more understandable error message.

I applied approach (1) to this snippet without success. However, approach (2) yielded this, which Flow passes:

```
type EqualsBy = <Obj, Value>(Obj => Value, Value, Obj) => boolean;
const equalsBy: EqualsBy = <Obj, Value>(f: Obj => Value, value: Value, obj: Obj) => (value === f(obj))
```

Note that all I did was to add type annotations to the arrow function. Honestly, I don't know why Flow had trouble checking this but I expect that it inferred some type that was too broad somehow.